# Importing into AWS DynamoDB with NodeJs causes memory leak

Tags: node.js, amazon-dynamodb, aws-sdk

I am trying to load a relatively large CSV file that is about 20,000,000 rows into a DynamoDB table. However after about 1,000,000 rows I get a memory dump

```
<--- Last few GCs --->

  136289 ms: Scavenge 1397.5 (1457.9) -> 1397.5 (1457.9) MB, 0.3 / 0 ms (+ 0.0 ms in 1 steps since last GC) [allocation failure] [incremental marking delaying mark-sweep].
  137127 ms: Mark-sweep 1397.5 (1457.9) -> 1397.5 (1457.9) MB, 841.8 / 0 ms (+ 0.0 ms in 1 steps since start of marking, biggest step 0.0 ms) [last resort gc].
  137989 ms: Mark-sweep 1397.5 (1457.9) -> 1397.5 (1457.9) MB, 858.6 / 0 ms [last resort gc].

<--- JS stacktrace --->

==== JS stack trace =========================================

Security context: 0000009B9BAB4639 <JS Object>
    1: stringify [native json.js:157] [pc=000003139D3AB8C4] (this=0000009B9BAAE771 <a JSON with map 0000004A38909B69>,u=0000009B9BAD8B09 <an Object with map 000001D75FD60619>,v=0000009B9BA041B9 <undefined>,I=0000009B9BA041B9 <undefined>)
    2: arguments adaptor frame: 1->3
    3: buildRequest [c:\Workspace\Archive\node_modules\aws-sdk\lib\protocol\json.js:~5] [pc=000003139D345857] (this=0000...

FATAL ERROR: CALL_AND_RETRY_LAST Allocation failed - process out of memory
```

This is my code. Is there anything I can do?

```
function processFile(fileName)
{

  var docClient = new AWS.DynamoDB.DocumentClient();

  var lineReader = readline.createInterface({
    input: fs.createReadStream(fileName)
  });

  var batchRecords = [];
  lineReader.on('line', function (line) {

    var split = line.split(',');
    var obj = {
      field1: split[0],
      field2: split[1],
      field3: split[2],
      field4: split[3],
      field5: split[4],
      field6: split[5]
    }

    batchRecords.push(obj);
    if (batchRecords.length == 25) {

      var putRequests = batchRecords.map((e) => {
        return {
          PutRequest: {
            Item: e
          }
        }
      });

      var params = {
        RequestItems: {
          "MyTable": putRequests
        }
      };

      // Comment out this line and runs through ok
      docClient.batchWrite(params, function (err, data) {
        if (err) console.log(err, err.stack);
      });

      batchRecords = [];

    }

  });

  lineReader.on('close', function() {
    console.log('Done');
  });

}
```

Answer (score 1):

You read the file correctly, line by line not trying to insert 20M line in memory, so no memory problem here.

But here, as you pointed out :

```
 // Comment out this line and runs through ok
      docClient.batchWrite(params, function (err, data) {
        if (err) console.log(err, err.stack);
      });
```

You'r referencing `data` in your callback and neither using it. Javascript GC don't like that. Try to remove it and see if it makes any differences :

```
// Comment out this line and runs through ok
          docClient.batchWrite(params, function (err) {
            if (err) console.log(err, err.stack);
          });
```

**[EDIT]**

Ok so my second guess would be related to `var batchRecords = [];` as it's declared outside the first callback.
Try not to batch at first, it would not be optimum, but there would be less code, and so more chance to find a leak.

My last guess would be that the internal `AWS.DynamoDB.DocumentClient` is leaking.

You may also want to not care about a leak, and pimp your node process with :

```
node --max-old-space-size=8192 script.js //do not limit to default 1.4Gb but 8gb.
```

I would care and not like to do that, but hey, I don't know what contraints you may have.

Comment: Thanks, but didn't seem to make a difference.

Answer (score -2):

Have you increased your provisioned write throughput?

Comment: Yes. Even if it is 10,000 it still gives the error. Possibly if we set it to 100,000 that might work, but would also cost a fortune to run.

Comment: The throughput for the DynamoDB service has no relation with your memory on your computer.